# Is Blender 2.82 compatible on Mac Mini (half 2010) and macos High Sierra?

Tags: osx

I have a Mac Mini (half 2010) and macos High Sierra.
I see only black surfaces when use eeve render.
Also a simple image texture do not appear.
Instead, the same blend file on 2.79b is ok.
Is Blender 2.82 compatible on my old mac?

Comment: I'm not sure (don’t quote me on that). But I'd say try a linux which most likely solves the most of your software related issues.

Comment: You need at least Mac OS 10.12 system, I doubt it would work on your old Mac but you can try